# Resize a CALayer with animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have added a CALayer to an image doing the following :

```
var menulayer = CALayer()
menulayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, menuimage.frame.size.width, menuimage.frame.size.height);
            menulayer.backgroundColor = bartint.CGColor
            menulayer.opacity = 1
            menuimage.layer.addSublayer(menulayer)
```

I want to animate the layer so that it reveals the image from left to right. I have tried this:

```
            let width = CGFloat(0)

            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
            self.menulayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width , 50)
            CATransaction.commit()
```

But the animation starts at the center of the image, how can I make it start from the left edge of the image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So animate the origin of the layer to shift it to the right until your image view is fully revealed. You will need to set `menuImage.layer.masksToBounds = true` so the cover layer isn't visible as it scrolls out of the frame of the image view.

Comment: Thank you very much ! for anyone interested it's `menuImage.layer.masksToBounds = true` in swift.

Comment: Oops. Yup, I still revert to Objective-C syntax sometimes.